# Login issue when spotify app is installed but not logged in spotify inside my android application

Tags: android, authentication, retrofit, spotify, spotify-app

Past couple of days i am facing a one problem : ***login in spotify in my application after installed spotify application in my android device.***

Before installed spotify application in my device it's proper working login & logout but when installing spotify appplication can't..

I am used these in my android studio.

```
compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-auth:1.0.0-beta12@aar'
compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player:1.0.0-beta12@aar'
```

Login With these code:

```
            AuthenticationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthenticationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID, AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN, REDIRECT_URI);

            builder.setScopes(new String[]{"user-read-private", "user-read-birthdate", "user-read-email", "streaming"});
            AuthenticationRequest request = builder.build();

            AuthenticationClient.openLoginActivity(activity, REQUEST_CODE, request);



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    final AuthenticationResponse authResponse = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, data);

    switch (authResponse.getType()) {
        // Response was successful and contains auth token
        case TOKEN:
            Log.d("AccessToken", "" + authResponse.getAccessToken());
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Login successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            onBackPressed();
            break;

        // Auth flow returned an error
        case ERROR:
            // Handle error response
            Toast.makeText(activity, "ERROR..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case EMPTY:
            Toast.makeText(activity, "EMPTY..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        // Most likely auth flow was cancelled
        default:
            // Handle other cases
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of issue do you have? Do you get any particular message?

Comment: yes i have error like: retrofit.RetrofitError: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Neither `spotify-auth` nor `spotify-player` use Retrofit. Maybe the problem is in another part of your code. Please post your code, otherwise it's extremely difficult to help you.

Comment: Everything seems correct to me. After the attempt to login do you receive any toast message (`"ERROR.."`, `"EMPTY.."`)?

Comment: no above retrofiterror just only show me

Comment: What kind of `authResponse.getType()` do you get after the login?

Comment: no login prompt doesn't open so can't get authResponse

Comment: So where do you get this error? Retrofit **is not** used in this two libraries. Please post your complete code, where the error **actually** happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109016/discussion-between-dhruv-raval-and-mattia-maestrini).

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. I think their auth flow in the new version of Spotify is broken. I can see the difference because login progress bars look different when the app is installed. I only have this issue when app is installed...